# what's the most efficient way to implement a returned calculated value in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

With the advent of rvalue references on top of Return Value Optimization, what would be the most efficient way to implement a core function like this?  How can I improve this implementation or should I leave it alone?

```
template <typename T>
string
to_string(const T& t)
{ 
  stringstream ss;
  ss << t;  
  return ss.str();
}
```

Obviously, I want to avoid copying or allocating memory if I can.
TIA.

Edit:  Thx to D. Rodriguez for that detailed answer.  Now, I have a second part to my question.  Is there a way to improve on this?

```
#define to_cstr( T ) (to_string( T ).c_str())
```

Of course I would like to avoid MACROs if I can, but if I copy and paste the template code above to return ss.str().c_str() and const char*, the temporary doesn't live long enough; although the code seems to run, valgrind complains (red light).

I haven't been able to come up with a cleaner solution than the MACRO above for to_cstr().  Any ideas how to improve, or should I also leave alone?

- Ken

Comment: http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/your-next-assignment/

Comment: Every time I read about the new language features in C++0x I'm really glad that I stopped writing C++ before it was released :)

Comment: You should create a second entry for the second (unrelated) question. As of the answer to that, I would recommend that you remove the macro altogether, it looks too much like a function for it's own good, as it is dangerous (it returns a pointer to the internals of a temporary), hiding it behind what looks like a function call will hide the danger from `const char* x = to_cstr( 5 );` [that construct is incorrect, and it would be without the macro, but at least you see the code upfront: `const char* x = to_string( 5 ).c_str();` is much easier to pick up in a code revision

Comment: Thanks, David!  I will update my code according to your recommendations.

Comment: B Tyler: don't comment on a language you don't speak. There are no new features here. `rvalue` and `lvalue` are from C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just leave it alone, it is efficient as it is. Even with C++03 compilers, the compiler will optimize the copies away.

Basically the compiler will make sure that the object in the calling code to `to_string`, the return statement of `to_string`, and the return statement of `ss.str()` all take exactly the same memory location. Which in turn means that there will be no copies.

Outside of what the standard mandates, the [calling conventions](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) for the return statement of a function that returns by value an object that does not fit in the registers in all 32/64 compilers I know (including VS, gcc, intel, suncc) will pass a pointer to the location in memory where the function is to construct the returned object, so that code will be translated internally to something in the lines of:

```
// Not valid C++! Just for illustration purposes
template <typename T>
to_string( uninitialized<string>* res, const T& t ) {
   stringstream ss;
   ss << t;
   stringstream::str( res, &ss ); // first argument is return location
                                  // second argument is `this`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I have a second part to my question. Is there a way to improve on this?

```
#define to_cstr( T ) (to_string( T ).c_str())
```

> Of course I would like to avoid MACROs if I can, but if I copy and paste the template code above to return ss.str().c_str() and const char*, the temporary doesn't live long enough; although the code seems to run, valgrind complains (red light).

You can make the compiler create a temporary value in the caller scope for you, so that the temporary lifetime corresponds to that of the expression where the temporary is created. Here is how:

```
struct TmpStr {
    mutable std::string s;
};

template<typename T>
char const* to_cstr(T value, TmpStr const& tmp = TmpStr()) {
    tmp.s = to_string(value); // your original function
    return tmp.s.c_str(); // tmp lives in the scope of the caller
}

int main() {
    printf("%s\n", to_cstr(1));
}
```

Comment: `tmp` does survive long enough to use with `printf`, but it is still a temporary and still gets destroyed at the semicolon.  This remains an extremely dangerous construct.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: You are right that with C++ you can shoot the whole leg off. Your risk assessment though is subjective.